# Get the name of an extracted directory from shutil.unpack_archive (Python3)

Tags: python-3.4

I have written a Python3 script to download a Drupal tarball. I do this using:

```
Drupal_latest_url = 'http://ftp.drupal.org/files/projects/drupal-8.0.0-beta11.tar.gz'
filename, headers = urllib.request.urlretrieve(Drupal_latest_url)
shutil.unpack_archive(filename, '/tmp', 'gztar')
```

My problem is that I then want to move the contents of the directory from the tarball (drupal-8.0.0-beta11/*) to a new folder.

How do I get the name of that directory, so how do I get "drupal-8.0.0-beta11" into a variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I still have this as unanswered... I don't know what my Python skills were at the moment I asked this questions (not very high level I assume) but now I'd simply do:

```
Drupal_latest_url.split('/')[-1].strip('.tar.gz')
```

To get the answer.

Comment: This assumes that whoever archived this directory didn't rename the tarball, which might be reasonable if you archived it yourself, but is not always true

Comment: @RyanQuey How would one handle different names in a tar.gz? I am running into this particular problem.

Comment: @illan probably just query the folder name that was extracted, maybe using e.g., [shutil.listdir()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207973/6952495) or something to that effect.